# Display image when src attribute is a file not a url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using a content script in my chrome extension that gets the src attributes (from several images from the user's active tab) in order to display them in my popup HTML file that is displayed when a browser action is clicked.  Certain images that I need to display use src values that are paths to local files.

#### Example:

src = "/image/17_x.px?wid=450&hei=500&bgcolor=xxx...etc"

- the src starts with a "/", has a brief identifier denoted by "17_x", followed by various attributes of the image.  Also itemprop = "image" is set on these image elements.  The "xxxx...etc" is just showing that other attributes and values are listed in the src

When I create a new image element with this "local" src, the desired image is not displayed in my popup html file.  Is there another way that I can use this image data to display the image within my extension?

Comment: So you're getting the images from the user's computer?

Comment: `?wid=450&hei=500&bgcolor=xxx...etc` that wont ever work with a local file path

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, no I am getting the images from any website that the the user of my extension is visiting.

Comment: Those are **relative** urls, not "local".

Answer (score 0):

Cause: `element.getAttribute("src")` or `$(...).attr("src")` return the original html markup.

Solution: use DOM property instead `element.src` or `$(...)[0].src` to return a full URL.